# modify single page cakephp

Tags: cakephp, edit

I want a single page ( like: domain.sg/contact ) to be editable but i think creating a new  database table, a model, a controller and the views isn't the best practice for this primitive problem. What do you advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a file to be editable without using a database you need to use file system functions along with an edit form either on the page or somewhere else.

Within the pages controller for your edit form:

```
public function edit_contact()
{
 //retrieve file's contents and output to view
 $file = fopen('/path/to/contact.ctp', w);
 $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
 $this->set('contents', $file_contents);
 if($this->request->is('post'))
 {
  fwrite($file, $this->request->data['contents']);
 }
 fclose($file);
}
```

View file:

```
//edit_contact.ctp
echo $this->Form->create('Edit Contact);
echo $this->Form->input('Content', array('type' => 'textarea', 'value' => $contents));
echo $this->Form->end('Update File');
```

You then create the contact.ctp that you want to be editable.

**Warning:** This form does no validation and would allow a user to input whatever they wanted including malicious code which could be used against you or other visitors.

Comment: I was about to do that, but i did not know where to store the content.

Comment: Create a view within the `Cake/app/View/Pages` folder